# How can I avoid valgrind report mem lost when making memory pointer arithmetic？

Tags: c, valgrind, memcheck

I'm using valgrind's memcheck on my soft;But I have problems in this: for some reason we will transform the malloced pointer before store,and transform back when use.Just like this:

```
char* ptr = (char*)malloc(1);
ptr = ptr + 1;
......
origin_ptr = ptr -1;
free(origin_ptr);

ptr = ptr + 1; <------ this will make valgrind to report memory lost;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's something that valgrind can't properly detect. Thus, you will have to write a suppression file that ignores the corresponding function.

Also, it's generally discouraged to do what you're doing, because `free` specifically demands that what you free is something that you got per `malloc`; now `+1-1` seems to be a NOP to me, too, but I suspect you do something more complex in the back hand.